# NSFetchedResultsController with mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I have a **Core data app** set up in the following manner:

- A shared `NSManagedObjectContext` with the `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`
- A shared `NSManagedObjectContext` with the `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`

These two contexts share a persistent store coordinator.

I have a `viewController` with a `collectionView` that uses a `NSFetchedResultsController` with the main queue context to keep the UI up to date.

My fetchedResults controller predicate looks like this:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"inRegion == YES"];
```

I use my private queue context to import network data and then merge changes onto the main context using `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`.

This technique works most of the time except when an objects inRegion goes from NO to YES. I perform a save which is followed by a merge onto the main queue context from the `privateQueueContextDidSave` notification. The change shows up in this notification. When I look at the `mainQueueContextObjectsDidChange` notification this change does not exist which explains why the fetched results controller does not update the UI.

My guess is that because `inRegion==NO`, the main context actually does not contain this object since it does not meet the predicate of the fetched results controller. When I remove the predicate, the change shows up in `mainQueueContextObjectsDidChange` notification. Doing everything in the main queue context solves the problem as well.

My question is, how do I maintain the benefits of off loading work from the main thread, keep my predicate, and core data stack the same and make sure that `mainQueueContextObjectsDidChange` notification (that `NSFetchedResultsController` uses for its delegate methods to report changes) contains all the required change information.

Comment: In [Track Changes in Other Threads Using Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) Apple recommends: "If the secondary context is not on the main thread, you should call processPendingChanges yourself at appropriate junctures."